# Is there any encapsulation software for constructing network protocol header?

Tags: python, networking

Is there any encapsulation software for constructing network protocol header?

You see my code, I can use `struct.pack()` to construct a ICMP packet.

```
import socket
import struct

rawsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.getprotobyname('icmp'))
packet = struct.pack('!BBHHH13s', 8, 0, 0, 1, 0, b'qasdssdehello')
chksum = checksum(packet)
```

but, I think it is complicated and difficult to use, is there any open source code of encapsulation `struct`? so I can construct a protocol packet easily.

Answer (score 2):

[Scapy](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) is library that allows construction of network packets, in a high-level way:

[Example for ICMP ping](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#icmp-ping):

> ICMP Ping Classical ICMP Ping can be emulated using the following
> command:
>
> ans, unans = sr(IP(dst="192.168.1.1-254")/ICMP())

> Information on live
> hosts can be collected with the following request:
>
> ans.summary(lambda s,r: r.sprintf("%IP.src% is alive") )